# Cant interact with PHP array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm turning grey headed over here..

Trying to interact with a array made from a csv file. When i echo parts of the array, it can be perfectly found. But when i try to use an array element in an IF sentence, it seems empty (its not empty).

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$filnavn="uploads/".$_COOKIE["f1l3nam3"];
$file = fopen($filnavn,"r");
$tael=0; //Used as a counter


while(! feof($file))
  {
  $resultat=fgetcsv($file,0,";");

if($resultat[19]!="DKK"){
    $tael++;
}

  }

echo $tael;
fclose($file);

?>
```

The result of this page is 0, it should be around 1320

`var_dump($resultat[19]);` gives me

```
string(7) "DKK" 
string(7) "DKK" 
string(7) "EUR" 
string(7) "GBP" 
string(7) "GBP" 
string(7) "GBP" 
string(7) "GBP" 
string(7) "DKK" 
string(7) "GBP" 
string(7) "GBP" 
string(7) "GBP" 
string(7) "GBP" 
string(7) "DKK" 
string(7) "DKK" 
string(7) "GBP" 
string(7) "GBP" 
string(7) "GBP" 
string(7) "GBP" 
string(7) "DKK" 
string(7) "GBP" 
string(7) "GBP" 
string(7) "GBP" 
string(7) "DKK" 
string(7)
```

`var_dump($resultat);` gives me

```
array(31) {
 [0]=> string(19) "246338756" 
 [1]=> string(41) "ContextType_Supplier" 
 [2]=> string(1) "" 
 [3]=> string(15) "0,00000" 
 [4]=> string(15) "0,00000" 
 [5]=> string(3) "0" 
 [6]=> string(3) "0" 
 [7]=> string(15) "0,00000" 
 [8]=> string(15) "0,00000" 
 [9]=> string(3) "0" 
 [10]=> string(3) "0" 
 [11]=> string(15) "0,00000" 
 [12]=> string(13) "311921" 
 [13]=> string(11) "17659" 
 [14]=> string(21) "08-05-2018" 
 [15]=> string(1) "" 
 [16]=> string(19) "246156901" 
 [17]=> string(17) "43534453" 
 [18]=> string(61) "Secret" 
 [19]=> string(7) "DKK"
 }
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Then show us the exact output of `var_dump($resultat[19]);`, please.

Comment: can you show the output of var_dump($resultat); ?

Comment: Just a small piece of advice... get into the habit of coding in english (I see you are using Danish variable names). It will make your code much more readable to others. Especially when asking for help in international forums.

Comment: `string(7) "DKK"` - see, that should be `string(3) "DDK"` - that it says `string(7)` instead means that you are probably dealing with data in a character encoding other than UTF-8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your condition like below:-

```
if(strpos(trim($resultat[19]), "DKK") === false){
    $tael++;
}
```

Or use

```
if(htmlentities($resultat[19]) != "DKK"){
    $tael++;
}
```

Comment: YES ! The solution with if(htmlentities($resultat[19]) != "DKK"){ did the trick. I have not even thought that this could be a solution at all. Many thanks

Comment: @Xelot  glad to help you :):)